# Java parsing long lines of text into multiple lines

Tags: java

I am new to programming and I would like some tips. 
I have a program that reads from a text file using the the following method:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
.....
```

This works but the problem is that some lines are long and I can't see all the text in the GUI. How should I tell Java to go to next line if length is equal to a certain amount?

Example text:

`A week after Mozart died, his ghost was discovered trying to erase his music. When asked why, it said "I'm decomposing.`

Instead of two lines, I want to parse it into four lines. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\n` is the newline character in Java.  String manipulation is somewhat complex, but you can get the length of a String, subsequences of a String and build new Strings from them.  I suggest you check the API for your version of Java -- [_Java 7 API_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Comment: "tell java to go to next line" means ignore the rest of the line and read the next line from the Text-File or you want to make line break in the read string?

Comment: @Rami.Q i think he wants to add \n to the sentence so that it displays as 4 lines. I'm thinking the problem can actually be solved using word wrap in the java console ;)

Comment: It sounds like your problem is with the presentation of the information, not the reading from the file.

Comment: if the line has for example 250 alphabets , i want java to show 100 and than go to the next line and show another 100 and than show 50. Not ignore the rest. yes in GUI. thank you

Comment: What do you mean with GUI?  Does your program have a graphical user interface?  If so, what graphical element are you using to display the text?  A text field should wrap the text automatically.  Actually, so should do your terminal emulator in case you are not programming a graphical interface yourself (which I'm pretty sure you are not).  Maybe all you need to do is change some settings of your terminal emulator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Large string split into lines with maximum length in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528045/large-string-split-into-lines-with-maximum-length-in-java)

Comment: I made JPanel and added 2 Jlabels to it. in one of them a question , and the answer in the other. Some answers are to long, and i dont know how to make it go to a new line after a certian amount of charackters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your comments, you are using JLabel for displaying the data.

to show multi-line text in JLabel just wrap your text in `<html>` tag like:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>your long text here ....</html>");
```

example:

```
String theReadLineFromTextFile = ....;

theReadLineFromTextFile = "<html>"+theReadLineFromTextFile+"</html>";
JLabel label = new JLabel(theReadLineFromTextFile);
//or 
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText(theReadLineFromTextFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do it in the gui, then some of the answers here will help: [Wrap the string after a number of characters word-wise in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212675/wrap-the-string-after-a-number-of-characters-word-wise-in-java)