# How to prevent word splitting on build output?

Tags: java, string

I am attempting to use ***substrings*** in order to prevent word splitting on the system output.

I have seen responses that split it by each word, but I want to do it only when necessary.

Original code:

```
System.out.println("This is a very extra long quote that doesn't break properly.");
```

Build output:

```
This is a very extr
a long quote that d
oesn't break proper
ly.
```

Desired build output:

```
This is a very
extra long 
quote that 
doesn't 
break properly.
```

Of course, I am not trying to have it that narrow-- I just want the word to break into a new line when the word splits.

Thank you anyone that helps! All responses are appreciated!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528045/large-string-split-into-lines-with-maximum-length-in-java

Comment: This is called "word wrapping" and is a common feature in many text editors and word processors. You should google the term to find more details about hints how to implement it yourself.

Comment: I understand of other solutions, but I noted for a solution using substrings. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking us to write and debug code for you? If so, you have come to the wrong place.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm asking if someone can assist as this is what the website is for.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am simply lost and trying to figure out my problem using substrings. Not looking for someone to write and debug code but to lean me in the right direction.

Comment: We are certainly here to help. However, don't expect us to do the work for you. You should edit your question to show us what you have tried so far. Also explain what problems you encounter with your attempts. The more detailed and narrowly focused your question the more we will be able to help you with exactly what you need. For more tips about asking good questions, check out our [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice -- That's the thing. I have no idea how to start-- I'm a bare beginner with Java and im confused as to how to attack this. And push in any direction would be helpful.

Comment: I suggest to start by turning off your computer. You should get a paper and pencil and write **in words** the steps you need to take to solve the problem. If I gave you several small pieces of paper each with one symbol on them. How would you figure out how to split the symbols into lines? What additional information might you need? (Okay, I'll give you this one: you also need the maximum line length.) At this point, don't worry about Java at all. Just describe the process in words (English or whatever natural language you are most comfortable with).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks headass that's exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of wrap method from WordUtils (Apache commons library [Link to documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#wrap-java.lang.String-int-))

The method makes use of wraplength and white spaces to wrap words from a string.

Comment: I am looking to use Substrings, not outside libraries such as Apache.