# How can I get Java to check a String for matches to a Pattern starting at the end?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a program that is reading lines of input from a file and must extract information from from each line using a regular expression. Each line is the absolute path to a file or folder in a file system that my application creates. Each line has the following format:

```
/root/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

What I need to do is separate the `String` into an array containing the first part of the path and then the last folder as follows:

```
["/root/folder1/folder2", "folder3"]
```

My idea of how to do this was to use a regular expression in conjunction with the `java.util.regex.Pattern#split(CharSequence, int)` method to split the string using the Pattern while limiting the size of the resultant array. However, since this method matches the pattern to the string starting at the beginning, this method won't work for me. I need something with similar functionality that would check the `String` for matches starting at the end rather that the beginning. Either that or I need a regular expression wizard to help me cook up a new regular expression to accomplish this.

Right now, I'm using the simple regex `"[/]"` to split the string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some of the methods in [`java.io.File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) might help, particularly when you need to handle different name-separator characters.

Comment: Have you seen this question? -> [Stack Overflow: Find Last Index Of by Regex in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560780/find-last-index-of-by-regex-in-java)

Comment: Do you have to use regex or regex-less approaches are also acceptable?

Comment: Yes, regex-less approaches are also acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use regex, `lastIndexOf()` will do the trick:

```
    String test = "/root/folder1/folder2/folder3";
    int index = test.lastIndexOf("/");
    String[] parts = { test.substring(0, index), test.substring(index + 1) };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts)); // [/root/folder1/folder2, folder3]
```

Comment: Yes this would definitely work for my purposes, and I may opt to do it this way given that regex compilation is so computationally intensive. That being said @Avinash Raj's regex is really slick and I could use that later on in my application.

Answer (score 3):

From your comment

> Yes, regex-less approaches are also acceptable

it looks like you can simply use `File` class and its `getName` and `getParrent` methods.

```
File f = new File("/root/folder1/folder2/folder3");
String[] data = {f.getParent(), f.getName()};

System.out.println(data[0]);
System.out.println(data[1]);
```

Output:

```
\root\folder1\folder2
folder3
```

Only potential problem here is that you will get `\` instead of `/` but if you are going to use these paths in Java this will not cause you any problem since Java accepts both separators. If not you can easily change them back with

```
String[] data = {f.getParent().replace('\\','/'), f.getName()};
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify. I'm creating a custom file system with its own version of the `File` class. This code is being used on the backend and it doesn't really suit my purposes to back the file system with standard java `File`s. I'll remember this in the future though.

Answer (score 1):

Just split each line according to the last forward slash.

```
String s = "/root/folder1/folder2/folder3";
String parts[] = s.split("/(?=[^/]*$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

`(?=[^/]*$)` asserts that the match must be followed by any character but not of `/` slash, zero or more times further followed by line end boundary.

**OR**

Through negative lookahead assertion.

```
String s = "/root/folder1/folder2/folder3";
String parts[] = s.split("/(?!.*/)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

**Output:**

```
[/root/folder1/folder2, folder3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found another, albeit cumbersome, way to do this.

```
String[] reverseNameAndPath = Pattern.compile("[,]")
                              .split(new StringBuilder(fileFolder[0])
                              .reverse()
                              .toString(), 2);
for(int n = 0; n < reverseNameAndPath.length; n++)
    reverseNameAndPath[n] = new StringBuilder(reverseNameAndPath[n])
                            .reverse()
                            .toString();
```